# Do we support Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: discussion

I saw this question, [GTK disappears while in sudo mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586992/gtk-disappears-while-in-sudo-mode), which appeared to be about a derivative Ubuntu release.

Do we support derivatives of Ubuntu? Or have I misidentified the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's funny the difference a week makes.

[Ubuntu MATE is official now](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-vivid-beta1/); it is supported on Ask Ubuntu.

Standard rules apply though so bugs and major pre-release issues should primarily be reported through the bug tracking tools on Launchpad.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll be setting up a new VM this weekend....

Comment: The Ubuntu MATE website linked in the answer is now dead.

Comment: @CarlH Works for me... What are you seeing?

Comment: @Oli 404. I'm at work; maybe our corporate firewall has blocked it, although I'm sure I've been on there from work before (at lunch time, obviously!).

Comment: @Oli The website is still accessible from home.

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm sure you don't need telling this but have a read of the release notes before installing UM in a VM - there's an issue about it being limited to 640x480 resolution.

Comment: @CarlH No troubles here running Mate 1404.1 at 1440x900 full screen. (max res of my monitor). I did give the VM 128M Video RAM to get there.....

Answer (score 7):

I think that is in the air right now, as they are on the way to be official and they have number releases corresponding with Ubuntu and still have "Ubuntu" in the title, as it seems the legal team is diligent in having derivatives remove that.

Since their goal is close compatibility, aka as pure as possible Ubuntu + Mate for the desktop - which can be added via ppa as well, it would be reasonable to let some through, till it's official.

However some still apply rules hard and fast without grey areas, and will still close until the day that happens.

This however isn't on the scale of mint, so I wouldn't be so fast to burn these questions.

So... tl;dr:

- Official? No.
- A recognized flavor? No.
- Is it Mint? NO.
- Will it be a flavor? [Maybe](https://ubuntu-mate.org/faq/).
- Should it be burned on sight? I'm willing to wait until they request them to stop using the word "Ubuntu" before we do that.

Comment: So what's the consensus? Wait?

Comment: Do what your conscience tells you to do.

Comment: I'll continue to use my best judgement until I hear different from the community.

Comment: Until very, very recently I thought Ubuntu Mate _was_ an official flavour of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion:

As long as it is NOT included in the [official list on Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours) or includes as an exception in [our help section](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) it is off topic.

---

In relation to that specific topic: closing something as a duplicate is better than closing something as off topic even when the question is related to an unofficial release. We are a friendly bunch though sometimes some of us can not prevent being firm or even (a bit) harsh but the 1st does an attempt to help the user and the 2nd just cuts of the user.

Comment: Thank you. I retracted my initial close vote on that as I was unsure how to proceed. I'm happy to see now that a duplicate was found which will likely be helpful to the OP.